# Have equal spacing between checkbox and labels

Tags: css

I have 10 checkboxes like this:

```
[]  Arts   []  Dance  []  Karate 
[]  Volleyball   []  Basketball
```

I have following css:

```
#tagstype_tags .tag_select {
    padding-left: 240px !important;
    width: 500px !important;
}
.tag_select label {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

How can i make them look like this?

```
[]  Arts         []  Dance        []  Karate 
[]  Volleyball   []  Basketball
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your markup. If you have for example a list with list elements you could do this

```
<ul>
<li class="checkboxLI"><input type="checkbox" name="volleyball"><label>Volleyball</label></li>
<li ...
</ul>
```

Then you can define the list elements to display 'inline-block' with a fixed width off 'whatever you like'. Your label would have e.g. 10px padding on the left

```
ul {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
.checkboxLI {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
.checkboxLI input {
    display:inline;
}
.checkboxLI label {
    display:inline;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

The only thing you can not avoid is that the label would wrap if they get too long....

Hope that helps,

Uwe

Comment: You can avoid label wrapping by including the following in the '.checkboxLI label' rule: white-space: nowrap;

Comment: You can  - but what's the point? Than it simply runs over the neighboring checkbox...